# JavaScript: доступ к стилю элемента

Tags: javascript

Почему в первых двух случаях алерт сообщит цвет элемента, а в третьем - нет?

Вариант 1. Цвет элемента задается в самом элементе:

```
<html>
<body>
  <p id="foo" style="color: blue">Some text</p>
  <script>
    (function() {
    var bar = document.getElementById("foo"), 
      style = bar.style;
    alert(style.color);
    }());
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вариант 2. Цвет элемента задается в JavaScript:

```
<html>
<body>
  <p id="foo">Some text</p>
  <script>
    (function() {
    var bar = document.getElementById("foo"), 
      style = bar.style;
    style.color = 'blue';
    alert(style.color);
    }());
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вариант 3. Стиль задается внутри блока <style> в head'е документа:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
   #foo {color: blue}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="foo">Some text</p>
  <script>
    (function() {
    var bar = document.getElementById("foo"), 
      style = bar.style;
    alert(style.color);
    }());
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [RETRIEVING CSS STYLES VIA JAVASCRIPT](http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2006/07/retrieving-css-styles-via-javascript/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что:

1. Вариант 1 - javascript обращается к
       атрибуту style и его свойству color.
2. Вариант 2 - javascript устанавливает
       атрибут style и свойство color и в
       последствии обращается к нему.
3. Вариант 3 - javascript не знает что
       вы прописали в css #id или .class
       используемого элемента, и работать с ними не может! Максимум менять ранее прописанное в css определенное(ые) или группу свойств(о).

Проще говоря в 3 примере отсутствует атрибут style к которому просят обратиться javascript.

Вариант 4 - если вы сами перепрочтете свой вопрос, то и сами все поймете!

Comment: @AlexWindHope есть возможность меня поправить!

Comment: @Palmervan так уже =)

Comment: Ага. Значит .style - это доступ к атрибуту. Понятно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
function getStyle(elem){
if(window.getComputedStyle) return getComputedStyle(elem, null);
else return elem.currentStyle;
```

}

возвращает коллекцию стилей для элемента передаваемого в виде аргумента.

Использование
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    color = getStyle(body).color;

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]?.. WTF? document.body, не?

Comment: Да так, спешил, и зафтыкал(